# HttpWebRequest getting wrong data

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to connect to a web server using `HttpWebRequest` and get some data. I managed to connect with following code:

```
    HttpWebRequest req= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.companyabc.com/security?action=authenticate");
    req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    req.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("https://www.companyabc.com"), new CookieCollection());
    string postData = "account_id=xxxx&password=xxxx";
    req.KeepAlive = true;

    byte[] send = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(postData);

    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = send.Length;
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0";

    Stream sout = req.GetRequestStream();
    sout.Write(send, 0, send.Length);
    sout.Flush();
    sout.Close();

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

To get the data I'm using:

```
    CookieContainer cookieJar = req.CookieContainer;
    foreach (Cookie cookie in res.Cookies)
    {
       cookieJar.Add(cookie);
    }
    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.companyabc.com/inside?action=displayHierarchyList&hierarchyId=157259&hierarchyLevel=2&selectedIndexMarket=157259&showPrices=false&hLevel=group&random=1423017429960");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    req.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    Stream dataStream = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

If I login using a web browser and enter this URL: https://www.companyabc.com/inside?action=displayHierarchyList&hierarchyId=157259&hierarchyLevel=2&selectedIndexMarket=157259&showPrices=false&hLevel=group&random=1423017429960

I get the following information in Json format:

```
{ "group" : [ { "id" : "159099", "name" : "Item1" }, { "id" :
  "158028", "name" : "Item2" }, { "id" : "159097", "name" : "Item2" }, {
  "id" : "158284", "name" : "Item4" }, { "id" : "157266", "name" :
  "Item5" }, { "id" : "158282", "name" : "Item6" }, { "id" : "157280",
  "name" : "Item7" }, { "id" : "157260", "name" : "Item8" }, { "id" :
  "157274", "name" : "Item9" }, { "id" : "157276", "name" : "Item10" }
 ]}
```

When I use `HttpWebRequest` I get the following:

> Sorry. An unexpected error has occurred. Please log out, close all
>   browser windows, and try again.

I have tried many things already with no luck, your help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the problem. With the help of fiddler I was able to noticed that in the response from the first request, there was a link, before sending the request for the data, I made a request to this link and it added some cookies need it for the request to work. Thank you.